# order of directives in robots.txt, do they overwrite each other or complement each other?

Tags: user-agent, robots.txt

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /privatedir/

User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Now, what are disallowed for Googlebot: /privatedir/, or the whole website / ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [original robots.txt specification](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html):

1. A bot must follow the first record that matches its user-agent name.
2. If such a record doesn’t exist, it must follow the record with `User-agent: *` (this line may not appear in more than one record).
3. If such a record doesn’t exist, it doesn’t have to follow any record.

So a bot never follows more than one record.

---

For your example this means:

- A bot that matches the name "Googlebot" is not allowed to crawl URLs with a path that starts with `/privatedir/`.
- A bot that doesn’t match the name "Googlebot" is not allowed to crawl any URL.

Comment: Excellent answer! Much clearer than the original robots.txt specification. Thanks!